# Kendo UI Export into excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 with Razor.
Here is my css and java script files code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.rtl.min.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" type="text/css" >
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/jszip.min.js")"></script>

but the problem is when I call kendo.all.min.js from live url mean when I add this url
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
then my grid sucessfully exported to excel but if I use this url 


 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
```

then upon exporting nothing happens and one more thing that kendo.all.min.js file in the project is same as in live url.
Kindly help.

Comment: The version you are refering may be any old one .. check the version with `kendo.version` in console

Comment: KishoreSahas I have updated kendo from kendo control panel and as i said i am using the same file as in live url. its very strange that from live url its working and from local path its not working...

Comment: when you use kendo.all.min.js from your local path - can you check the console for any 404 errors ... basically i would check my console & network tab to see if there is any error reported ... if due to  some reason the file kendo.all.min.js is not rendered by your server you will face this problem .... so do check the network & console to see if anything is reported...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved!
At my end its not working while debugging but when I deployed on my local server then it started working there.